# Avoding maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I have the following codes which will be running 24 hours but only after 10-20 minutes I get error maximum recursion depth reached. My code is folowing

```
def startEnd():
    flag = 0
    f = open('file')
    lq = f.readlines()
    cur2 = lq[0]
    cur1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    while flag == 0:
        if cur1 == cur2: # cur2 is datetime read from file
            q.put(True)
            flag = 1
        else:
            flag = 0
    startEnd()
```

How can I avoid recursion in the following code? I need to come out of while loop since cur2 value changes.

My other question is that will following code will also lead to recursion depth error in the long run since my code need to be run 24 hours.

```
def planIncr():
    f=open('input.txt')
    lines=f.readlines()
    cycle_time = int(lines[1])
    f.close()
    q2.put(True)
    threading.Timer(cycle_time, planIncr).start()
```

Comment: Make them non-recursive is the simple answer. The best way to do that  (short of just a master while-loop) depends on what you're trying to do and if you can use some frameworks/what OS you're on etc...

Comment: How does that function ever even reach the recursive call? That loop shouldn't ever stop. Even if `cur1` weren't a different type from `cur2`, it would never go from not being equal to suddenly being equal. You'd just keep setting `flag = 0` forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the first function - just put everything inside a while loop:

```
def startEnd():
    while True:
        flag = 0
        f = open('file')
        lq = f.readlines()
        cur2 = lq[0]
        cur1 = datetime.datetime.now()
        while flag == 0:
            if cur1 == cur2: # cur2 is datetime read from file
                q.put(True)
                flag = 1
            else:
                flag = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that your second function **is not** recursive - it will never trigger a recursion depth error.  Yes, `planIncr` is passed to `threading.Timer`, but not *executed* by that call.  `planIncr` is executed by some other thread later, and the thread that called `planIncr` to begin with sees `planIncr` return right away.